# what should be the value of action attribute if we have multiple forms on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If we have two *forms*, and if we specify:

```
action ="/";
```

Then how should we handle them in a server file (using express). I am confused because we can only specify `app.get("/", func);`

Comment: Assign each form to a different action path and in the server treat each case accordingly